# Auth0 authentication with Gridsome server side rendering breaks with window is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, auth0, server-side-rendering, gridsome

I've implemented the auth0 Vuejs according to their tutorial with Gridsome, and it worked fine in develop.
However, when I run `gridsome build` the build fails because `window` is undefined in a server context.

I've found a few issues in Auth0-js lib that claim that Auth0 should only be used in client side, however, due to the way Gridsome works, I can't seem to find a way to only load the Auth0-js in client side.

Gridsome has main.js where I would add plugins, and in there, I define the routing for authentication.

Main.js

```
import AuthServicePlugin from '~/plugins/auth0.plugin'
import auth from '~/auth/auth.service'

export default function (Vue, { router, head, isClient }) {
  ...
  Vue.use(AuthServicePlugin)
  //Handle Authentication
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.path === "/auth/logout" || to.path === "/auth/callback" || auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }

    // Specify the current path as the customState parameter, meaning it
    // will be returned to the application after auth
      auth.login({ target: to.path });

  })
```

Based on a Gatsbyb.js auth0 implementation tutorial, I've tried to exlude auth0-js from webpack loading with `null-loader`

gridsome.config.js

```
configureWebpack: {
    /*
     * During the build step, `auth0-js` will break because it relies on
     * browser-specific APIs. Fortunately, we don’t need it during the build.
     * Using Webpack’s null loader, we’re able to effectively ignore `auth0-js`
     * during the build. (See `src/utils/auth.js` to see how we prevent this
     * from breaking the app.)
    */
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /auth0-js/,
          use: 'null-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
```

I would love to get some ideas about how to include and load Auth0 only in client side context with Gridsome

Comment: From your second code snippet `(See src/utils/auth.js to see how we prevent this from breaking the app.)` Go [here](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-gatsby-with-auth0/) and search the page for `// src/utils/auth.js` - about 1/4 of the way down the page they supply code for how they prevent this from breaking the app (did you read those comments?)

Comment: I followed that exact tutorial, and couldn't get the auth.js from their example match with the auth.js from their VUE example. For vue, you need to create a vue plugin.
And apparently this creates the difference, since the webpack config imports all of the plugin requirements at build time on the server, and auth0-js code has references to window objects

Comment: Any luck @Altryne? Having the same problem

Comment: @HelderLucas actually moved to nuxtjs and it's much simpler with @nuxtjs/auth module, took me half a day without issues

Comment: @Altryne thanks for the reply. Exactly the same route I'm inclined to take

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with using **Firebase Authentication** with Gridsome.

It seems that code in the `created()` lifecycle hook gets executed in the Gridsome build process (which is a server environment), but code in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook only executes in the browser!

The solution was to put all the code that should only run in the client in the `mounted` lifecycle hook.

```
mounted() {
  // load the `auth0-js` here
  ...
}
```

---

In my instance (with Firebase Auth) this was the solution:

In the Default Layout component:

```
const app = import("firebase/app");
    const auth = import("firebase/auth");
    const database = import("firebase/firestore");
    const storage = import("firebase/storage");

    Promise.all([app, auth, database, storage]).then(values => {
      // now we can access the loaded libraries !
    });
}
```